# Wrapping BackdropFilter in ClipOval removes blur effect

Tags: flutter, imagefilter, flutter-layout

I'd like to create a circular widget which blurs the background behind it, like so:

```
new BackdropFilter(
  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0),
  child: new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(0.5)),
    child: Text("Something")
    )
  )
```

This works, but shows blur for the full rectangle around the BoxDecoration, outside of the blue area. So, I thought I'd wrap it in a ClipOval to clip that away, like so:

```
ClipOval ( child: new BackdropFilter(
  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0),
  child: new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(0.5)),
    child: Text("Something")
    )
  ))
```

Unfortunately that leads to no blur effect being rendered. Am I missing something, or is this a flutter bug?

Comment: looks like a bug, might be a good idea to ask this on the issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

I try to use `Positioned > ClipRect > BackdropFilter` and see it works.

```
double _sigmaX = 0.0; // from 0-10
double _sigmaY = 0.0; // from 0-10
double _opacity = 0.1; // from 0-1.0
double _width = 350;
double _height = 300;
double _blurWidth = _width / 2;
double _blurHeight = _height / 2;

Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Image.asset(
      'assets/images/background.jpg',
      width: _width,
      height: _height,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    FlutterLogo(size: 80, colors: Colors.red),
    Positioned(
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: _blurWidth,
      height: _blurHeight,
      // Note: without ClipRect, the blur region will be expanded to full
      // size of the Image instead of custom size
      child: ClipRect(
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: _sigmaX, sigmaY: _sigmaY),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(_opacity),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Source: [article on Medium](https://medium.com/fluttervn/how-to-make-blur-effect-in-flutter-using-backdropfilter-imagefilter-559ffd8ab73?source=friends_link&sk=044ab21dd506a6146624ec3758b0d1b4)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code hope it will work for you

```Dart
ClipRect(child: ClipOval(
                    child: BackdropFilter(
                      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade200.withOpacity(0.3),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text('Frosted',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                )
```